# Isn't Stress-Energy Tensor of Maxwell field in presence of charges gauge variant?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gauge-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, gauge-invariance

Versions of this question have been asked on this site before but have not directly addressed by concern. In the $(+---)$ convention the EM lagrangian in the presence of charge sources is

$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{\sqrt{-g}}{4} F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} + \sqrt{-g} j^\mu A_\mu.
$$

Using the equation
$$
T_{\mu \nu} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial g^{\mu \nu} }
$$

we get
$$
T_{\mu \nu} =  - F_{\mu}^{\: \, \alpha} F_{\nu \alpha} + g_{\mu \nu} \frac{1}{4} F^{\alpha \beta} F_{\alpha \beta} + g_{\mu \nu} j^\alpha A_\alpha
$$

The first two terms correspond to the stress-energy tensor of a free $(j = 0)$ EM field. The third term, however, is not gauge invariant. Isn't this a problem? The right hand side of $G_{\mu \nu} = 8 \pi G T_{\mu \nu}$ should not depend on gauge. Isn't there an ambiguity when you have charged matter in a gravitational field?

Comment: "The third term, however, is not gauge invariant. Isn't this a problem?" Yes, it *is* a problem. You skipped the matter theory this term makes gauge invariant through its gauge variation. This matter term needs the third term just as the third term needs it.

Comment: What if our matter theory is just a bunch of point charges, with the matter action just being the proper time of the particles? It seems there is no $A_\mu$ in that part of the action so there is no other term that could possibly compensate to make the total $T_{\mu \nu}$ gauge invariant.

Comment: The derivatives on the part of the charges contribute to the gauge variation. The third term is effectively their gauge covariant completion.

Comment: Which term are you referring to for the derivatives on the part of the charges? I'm having a difficult time understanding which term. Are you also referring to varying with respect to $g^{\mu \nu}$ (to get $T_{\mu \nu}$) or $A_\mu$?

Comment: The missing term of evolving matter: the one you skipped. It too contributes to the stress energy tensor. Fix gauge invariance term and bother with metrics and geometry later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I understand the answer. I was really thinking about this in terms of point particles coupled to the gauge field. So the interaction term is

$$
\mathcal{L}_{\rm int} = j^\mu A_\mu = q \int d\lambda \frac{dx^\mu}{d \lambda}A_\mu (x(\lambda)).
$$
where $\lambda$ parameterizes the path.

Note that there is actually no metric dependence in this term. Therefore
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}_{\rm int}}{\partial g^{\mu \nu}} =  0
$$
and there is therefore no contribution from this term to $T_{\mu \nu}$. What confused me was that, in my original question, when I wrote
$$
\mathcal{L}_{\rm int} = \sqrt{-g} J^\mu A_\mu
$$
I assumed that $J$ was independent of $g^{\mu \nu}$ which is actually not the case. In fact,

$$
J^\mu(x)= \frac{j^\mu(x)}{\sqrt{-g}} = \frac{q}{\sqrt{-g}} \int d\lambda \frac{d x^\mu(\lambda)}{d \lambda}\delta^4(x - x(\lambda) ).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Our charge coupling term is of the form

\begin{equation}
S = \int_U j^\alpha A_\alpha 
\end{equation}

Now take the gauge transformation. We have

\begin{equation}
A_\alpha \to A_\alpha + \partial_\alpha f
\end{equation}

giving us the difference

\begin{equation}
\delta S = \int_U (j^\alpha \partial_\alpha f)
\end{equation}

As a Noether current, the electric current obeys the relation

\begin{equation}
\partial_\alpha j^\alpha = 0
\end{equation}

Therefore, we can integrate by parts to obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
\delta S &=& \int_{\partial U} f n_\alpha j^\alpha - \int_U ((\partial _\alpha j^\alpha) \alpha f)\\
&=& \int_{\partial U} f n_\alpha j^\alpha
\end{eqnarray}

with $n$ the normal vector to the boundary of integration. The action then only differs by a surface term. In general, we don't consider boundary terms for the EM action (we just pick $M$ as the volume of integration which has no boundary), but things [will get more complicated](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/15564/1/Relationalism%20in%20field-space_final5.pdf) if we allow our volume have a boundary.

But in terms of the stress-energy tensor, which is a local quantity for which we can always pick the appropriate volume around it, this isn't an issue. The difference from the gauge vanishes and therefore its variation does as well.